# Xbox one stream laptop

Tags: xbox-one

I have a laptop with an hdmi port. I want to be able to switch over to that in the Xbox, but there is no “TV” app or anything to switch to the hdmi input. How can I do this? To clarify more **i want to have my laptop display in the Xbox, not the Xbox display on the laptop**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/live-tv/set-up-live-tv) has this information. Although it appears to be tailored to using a cable or set-top box, I'd assume the procedure will work the same for a laptop:

> Select Live TV Setup from the Entertainment hub. You'll be asked a series of questions in order to complete your TV setup.
>
> On the Watch TV on your Xbox screen, select either Set up your cable or satellite box or Set up your USB TV tuner. This depends on the source of your TV signal.
>
> The Let’s watch TV screen will try to detect an HDMI-in signal.

Comment: I see. I was trying to do it through settings which didn’t work. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, sorry I didn't understand your issue before

Comment: Np, it’s hard to type good questions on a tiny phone (also why I wasn’t able to find an answer googling I think)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not particularly clear about the type of content that you want on the the Xbox big screen, but a more basic solution would be to simply connect the laptop to your television using the laptops HDMI output and an HDMI cable.

However, If your intention is just to easily and simply stream specific movies, music et cetera from the laptop without having to physically connect it to your Xbox or television, then Plex is easy alternative.  This is an free application which you install on your laptop and your Xbox One, and allows you to easily stream any content from your laptop to any device (Xbox One PlayStation et cetera.)

Both the laptop and the Xbox One must be connected to the same internal home network

The Xbox One is designed to support this kind of streaming natively, however I have never been able to get it work! Plex is far easier and works like a dream!

Comment: My tv only has one port. I have a pled server set up, however I want to do schoolwork from my chair in my room instead of going upstairs to the desk.

Comment: @MarkDeven but how would you control the laptop using just the Xbox?

Comment: I can have a mouse on my chair, and use the Xbox controllers usb keyboard by plugging the dongle into my laptop